# Advanced Search Box Not Showing Results or Connecting to the Show View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, advanced-search

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails, and I am trying to implement an advanced search. The advanced search is to search for books and their categories.

Please let me know if you need additional information.

I have implemented the advanced search form view, new view and show view.

But when I try to search for books, it doesn't display the search results neither doesn't render the show view for searches. It rather renders a new view page for Advanced Search.

Here is my Searches Controller Code

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:keywords, :category)
  end
end
```

Here is my Search Model Code

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
  def search_books

    books = Book.all

    books = books.where(["name LIKE ?","%#{keywords}%"]) if 
      keywords.present?
    books = books.where(["category LIKE ?",category]) if 
      category.present?

 return books

 end
end
```

Here is my Searches _form.html.erb Code

```
<%= form_with(model: search, local: true) do |form| %>
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.text_field :keywords, {placeholder: 'Keywords', 
      :class => 'form-control pb_height-50 reverse'} %>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.text_field :category, {placeholder: 'Category', 
      :class => 'form-control pb_height-50 reverse'} %>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block 
       pb_btn-pill  btn-shadow-blue', value: 'Search'%>
   </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is my Searches new.html.erb Code

```
<% content_for :title, "New Search" %>

 <section class="pb_cover_v3 overflow-hidden cover-bg-indigo cover- 
    bg-opacity text-left pb_gradient_v1 pb_slant-light menu-section" 
    id="section-home">

 </section>

 <section class="pb_section bg-light pb_slant-white pb_pb-250" 
   id="section-features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-12 relative align-self-center">

        <form action="/search" class="bg-white rounded pb_form_v1">
          <h2 class="mb-4 mt-0 text-center">Advanced Search</h2>
          <hr>

          <%= render 'form', search: @search %>

          <hr>
          <%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
        </form>

       </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Here is my Searches show.html.erb Code
    <% content_for :title, "Search Result" %>

```
   <section class="pb_cover_v3 overflow-hidden cover-bg-indigo 
     cover-bg-opacity text-left pb_gradient_v1 pb_slant-light menu- 
     section" id="section-home">

   </section>

  <section class="pb_section pb_slant-white pb_pb-250" id="section- 
  features">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row titlerow">
        <h1><%= Search Result %></h1>
          <p><%= link_to 'Back', new_search_path %></p>

            <% if @search.search_books.empty? %>

              <p>No Records Found</p>

            <% else%>

               <% @search.search_books.each do |c| %>
                <br>

               <div class="div">
               <h1><%= c.name %></h1>
               <p>Category: <%=c.category %></p>

              </div>

             <% end %>

           <% end %>      
          </div>
        </div>
 </section>
```

I need some assistance on how my search results can be displayed on the show view of the searches, instead of the Advanced Search page re-rendering the a new search page each time I click the Search Button of the Advanced Search. I need a way to connect the Show View of the Advanced Search to the New Advanced Search Page, so that it can display search results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it.

On the new.html.erb

```
<section class="pb_section bg-light pb_slant-white pb_pb-250" id="section-features">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-12 relative align-self-center">

            <form action="/search" class="bg-white rounded pb_form_v1">
              <h2 class="mb-4 mt-0 text-center">Advanced Search</h2>
              <hr>

              <%= render 'form', search: @search %>

              <hr>
              <%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
            </form>

          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

I simply changed the **form** tag to to a **div** tag, and also removed the **action** attribute from the form tag.

I have learnt a lot in the process.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**